# Where clause doesn't work in SQL because of space character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
Select Name from tblAnimal where Id=1
```

Returns: My Pet

```
Select Id from tblAnimal where Name='My Pet'  --I copy/pasted this value in SSMS!
```

Return empty changeset (WHY?)

After some research I found out that it can be Char(10) and Char(13). So, I guess, when I do copy paste of My Pet, it automatically converts Char(10) to Space for Windows environment?

Because this:

```
Select id from tblAnimal where Name like '%My%'
```

returns 1
While

```
select id from Animal where Name like '%My %'
```

returns nothing.

Questions.
1. Why this is happening?
2. How to fix this (Production database, several million records)
3. How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You can use an `_` as a wildcard. `LIKE '%My_Pet%'`

Comment: @njk, Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not a solution in my case, because I do not control 'My Pet' search string. It comes from the user. I just want sql server to act normal and treat all special spaces like regular spaces

Comment: Chars 10/13 is a carriage return/linefeed. How is this user entering a <CR><LF> in their string? Or do you mean that those values are stored within the records?

Comment: Is that column going to be a fixed size? You want to use `nvarchar` instead due to the encoding.

Comment: @MichaelTodd, I already have those records in the database. What I do not understand is why when I copy those values to clipboard they are treated as spaces.

Comment: @njk, I'm using nvarchar(max)

Comment: Maybe to try update data with replacing?

Comment: Tried above. Works as intended. See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96bdf/6/0)

Comment: This is a business rule, not necessarily a database problem. While it presents a general problem _today_ you really should consider if this needs to be done closer to the UI and not rely on the database for this sort of validation.

Comment: @jcolebrand Regardless of where you think validation should occur, the safest and quickest way to implement validation for all of the various apps and ad hoc queries that might be putting junk into the database is at the database layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char 10 and char 13 are newline and carriage return -- they're NOT spaces, even though they appear as such on grid results.  If you're viewing your results in SSMS, best to tell it to view your results as Text (ctrl+T, or on your toolbar).  If you do this, you'll see if the result is really:

```
My Pet
```

Or

```
My
Pet
```

Results to Grid will show it as `My Pet` on one line, as that's how the grid works.  Results as Text will show new lines, even for a single record, so you'll better see exactly what data is in your table.

Comment: @user194076 And if it _does_ break the result into two lines, then the problem is that the <CR><LF> are embedded into the column in your table so the user will _never_ be able to search for that result until you change the data, i.e. convert it from <CR><LF> to a space).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you're correct. as soon as use text mode, it looks like two lines.

Comment: @MichaelTodd, do you guys know if there's a setting on a column that can prevent Char(10) or Char(13) or it should be a custom trigger?

Comment: No.  It's a valid character.  Nothing to prevent it from being added.  You could scrub it yourself.  But I would do that as a one-time thing.  After that, you should be much more focused on making sure only good data makes it to your DB.  It's the only choice if you want to keep your DB running effectively.

Comment: `Nothing to prevent it from being added.` Um, what? How about a check constraint, e.g. `CHECK (CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), col) = 0)`? This allows you to protect the table *in addition to* adding validation to all of your apps and teaching all of your co-workers who might be running ad hoc queries.

Comment: Also, no offense, but this answer addresses only a minor part of the question.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that constraint possibility. +1 to your answer from me.

Answer (score 6):

To clean up the data, replacing a CR/LF pair with a space:

```
UPDATE dbo.table
  SET column = REPLACE(REPLACE(column, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ' ')
  WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), column) + CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), column) > 0;
```

And to address the point about *preventing* this data in the first place, you *most certainly can* prevent it, and this is where that prevention should start - as close to the data as possible, since you have less control over all of the external ways that people can stuff garbage into your tables. Assume you have a table already:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.blat(col VARCHAR(32));
```

To add a constraint is simple:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.blat ADD CONSTRAINT ck_col_NoCRLF
  CHECK(CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), col) + CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), col) = 0);
```

Now:

```
INSERT dbo.blat(col) SELECT NULL;
```

Works.

```
INSERT dbo.blat(col) SELECT 'howdy';
```

Works.

```
INSERT dbo.blat(col) SELECT 'howdy
    partner';
```

Fails with:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ck_col_NoCRLF". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.blat", column 'col'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

You might also consider adding a variety of other special characters - `CHAR(9)` (<kbd>tab</kbd>) is a common one as well.